# How to ignore tag when set grid-template-columns property?

Tags: html, css

How to display only the `div` in three columns using css grid for this html structure?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/jon9090-the-typescripter/pen/xxpWQmZ)

```
section {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 150px);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
div { background:blue;height:30px;}

<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <span></span>
  <div>2</div>
  <span></span>
  <div>3</div>
  <span></span>
  <div>4</div>
  <span></span>
  <div>5</div>
  <span></span>
  <div>6</div>
  <span></span>
</section>
```

I use `grid-template-columns` to display three `div` in row. but I also want to ignore the `span`. is there some css property that can ignore the `span` when set the columns?

the expected results should be:

```
 div1 div2 div3
 div4 div5 div6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to the span between div element that are considered as other column

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 150px);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

div {
  background: blue;
  height: 30px;
}

span {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <span></span>
  <div>2</div>
  <span></span>
  <div>3</div>
  <span></span>
  <div>4</div>
  <span></span>
  <div>5</div>
  <span></span>
  <div>6</div>
  <span></span>
</section>
```

an idea can be to set section with position:relative and span position:absolute to place span inside relative element

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 150px);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

div {
  background: blue;
  height: 30px;
}

span {
  background: red;
  z-index: 9;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <span>coucou</span>
  <div>2</div>
  <span></span>
  <div>3</div>
  <span></span>
  <div>4</div>
  <span></span>
  <div>5</div>
  <span></span>
  <div>6</div>
  <span></span>
</section>
```

or if you don't want span between div you can use display:none

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 150px);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

div {
  background: blue;
  height: 30px;
}

span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <span>coucou</span>
  <div>2</div>
  <span></span>
  <div>3</div>
  <span></span>
  <div>4</div>
  <span></span>
  <div>5</div>
  <span></span>
  <div>6</div>
  <span></span>
</section>
```

Comment: Yeah I know it's because the span. but I can't remove the span (its generate by third party). my question is can I make grid to ignore the span?

Comment: yes see my last edit if span is placed as `position:absolute` inside section with `position:relative` you will be able to manage their placement

Comment: or use display: none if you truly don't want to display them